# Pairing duplicate elements in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, loops

I am trying to pair the duplicate elements of an array and count the pairs.

When given array is : [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20], I'm expecting numberOfPairs to be 3. Because there are 2 pairs of 10s and 1 pair of 20.

My "if condition" is checking if current element's index is first index or not. If it is not the last index, it means that there is a duplicate of the current element. So I'am adding 1 to numberOfPairs.

For input [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20], my numberOfPairs is 2 but it should be 3.
For input [1 1 3 1 2 1 3 3 3 3], myNumberOfPairs is not printing at all? But instead it should be 4.

My What am I missing here?

```
func sockMerchant(n: Int, ar: [Int]) -> Int {
    // Write your code here
    var array = ar
    var numberOfPairs = 0
    
    for i in 0..<array.count {
       var element = array[i]
       let indexOfLastElement = array.lastIndex(of: element)
       let indexOfFirstElement = array.firstIndex(of: element)
       print("indexOfLastElement is \(indexOfLastElement)")
       print("indexOfFirstElement is \(indexOfFirstElement)")
       
       if indexOfFirstElement != indexOfLastElement {
           numberOfPairs += 1
           array.remove(at: indexOfFirstElement!)
           array.remove(at: indexOfLastElement!)
           continue
       }
       return numberOfPairs
    }
     return numberOfPairs
 }
```

Comment: It is quite simple: Start with a simple example and *debug* your program. Single-step through the code, inspect variables. At which point does the program not behave as you thought it would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've solved the problem as below, thanks to @Vym and @Martin R.

```
func sockMerchant(n: Int, ar: [Int]) -> Int {
// Write your code here
var array = ar
var numberOfPairs = 0
var newArray = [Int]()
var done = false

for i in 0..<array.count {
   let element = array[i]
   let indexOfLastElement = array.lastIndex(of: element)
   let indexOfFirstElement = array.firstIndex(of: element)
   
   if indexOfFirstElement != indexOfLastElement {
       newArray.append(element)
       numberOfPairs = newArray.count/2
       done = true
   }
   
}
if done == true {
    return numberOfPairs
}
 return numberOfPairs
```

}

Comment: Glad you could get to a working solution.

P.S. I, personally, didn't accuse you in cheating of any sort. Please avoid using all caps next time and keep in mind this is a Q&A website where "opinion-based" answers are discouraged.

Comment: No worries! A downvote is a downvote - don't stress over it. You don't have to explain yourself.

Comment: Thank you Vym. I really appreciate that. Pretty new around here, getting used to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're mutating your `array` by calling `remove(at:)` at the same time as you're accessing it which is why you're having these weird side effects.

I assume you're trying to solve a Leetcode task (or something similar), so I won't provide a solution upfront. My suggestion for you is to think of an algorithm that doesn't involve changing the contents of the List while you're reading these contents of that same List.

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with @MartinR that in such cases you should place breakpoints and go throught your code line by line, glad you've found your mistake by yourself.

But also in terms of performance, `lastIndex` and `firstIndex` are very heavy operations, because they may go thought all items and find nothing, which makes [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of your algorithm around O(log n). In such cases dictionary is widely used(if you're not much limited with the space).

You can use value as a `key` and count as a `value` for a dictionary and count all items, then just sum like this:

```swift
func sockMerchant(ar: [Int]) -> Int {
    ar.reduce(into: [Int:Int]()) { map, value in
        map[value, default: 0] += 1
    }.reduce(0) { sum, count in
        sum + count.value / 2
    }
 }
```

Comment: This doesn’t return the correct result. Please test with the examples in the question or a simple test case, [1,1,1,1]

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks, I’ve misunderstood the question a little bit, updated answer should work

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language `reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value/2 }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Of course you can do that. But I think naming the arguments greatly improves readability; I only use shorthand when the calculations are quite simple. The same goes for dictionary types: I wish the author was clearer about what's going on here. Also swift can be very bad at showing errors and giving suggestions in code with `[:]`.

Comment: What does the map[value, default :0] += 1 actually do?

Comment: @artikes123 it's equivalent of `map[value] = (map[value] ?? 0) + 1`. Like if there's a value for this key, it increases it by one, otherwise - it uses  default value of `0` and add `1` to it.

Comment: @artikes123 it is called [Dictionary Key-based subscript with default value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov it depends. If you name a keyvalue element as count it doesnt help readability. It just makes it harder.

Comment: @LeoDabus This is still better than `$1`. Suggest your own version, and I'll change it if I think it's more appropriate.